# length of tr is not counting using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML table having number of rows and my source is

```
<div>
<table id="grdAddressbook" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0px" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;" rules="all">
<tbody>
<tr>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I tried following codes for finding the number of table rows.

```
$("#grdAddressbook tr").length;

$("#grdAddressbook tbody").children().length;

$("#grdAddressbook >tbody>tr").length;

$("#grdAddressbook").find("tbody").children().length;

$($("#grdAddressbook").find("tbody")).children().length;
```

but all the above code returns '0' eventhough there are more than 0 tr.
I had included jquery in source.

it is seen in firebug like below

```
>>> $('#grdAddressbook tr').length;
0
```

The table is inside an ifreme with id 'ifrmAdBook' so I tried this too

```
var i=$("#ifrmAdBook").find("#grdAddressbook");
$(i).find("tr").length;
```

This is also returning 0

Comment: Is that table generated with AJAX ?

Comment: Works fine as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/95BMx/.

Comment: It was a gridview control which converted to table after rendering

Comment: Additional codes required.!

Comment: Any chance you have another element with the same id?

Comment: $('#<%= grdAddressbook.ClientID %> tr').length as you are using server side control, try to use with ClientID, as it is differently generated in HTML

Comment: Are you calling that code either inside a DOM ready handler or by placing the `<script>` tag **after** the HTML for the table? If not it's simply a case of the elements not existing (and therefore not being able to be matched) when your code executes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jagruti/bx9qk/)

```
> $('#grdAddressbook tr td').size();
```

Comment: its working fine in my demo http://jsfiddle.net/jagruti/bx9qk/ please check it once.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine -- **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FvCLG/)**

HTML

```
<div>
<table id="grdAddressbook" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0px" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;" rules="all">
<tbody>
<tr>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

JS

```
alert("tr length: " + $("#grdAddressbook tr").length);

alert("tbody length: " + $("#grdAddressbook tbody").children().length);

alert("tbody tr length: " + $("#grdAddressbook >tbody>tr").length);

alert("children: " + $("#grdAddressbook").find("tbody").children().length);

alert($($("#grdAddressbook").find("tbody")).children().length);
```

Answer (score 0):

check ur table is developed before executing the length

```
if ($('#grdAddressbook')[0])
{   
alert($("#grdAddressbook tr").length);    
}
```